# Could not upload file larger than 10M

Tags: php, apache

We have problem when uploading file with size more than 10M. we have set ini our `php.ini` file as follow:

```
post_max_size = 256M 
upload_max_filesize = 256M 
max_execution_time = 1800 
max_input_time = 1800 
memory_limit = 256M
```

We ensure that this `php.ini` is in used, no other setting in .htaccess nor in the code, no error found in log file nor in other notifications. Upload file with size less than 10M is okay.
This make us headache.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: did you restart your apache ?

Comment: what do you mean by "problem"? did you debug your php app? what actually happens when you send bigger file? did you set php errors and warnings to something like ALL?

Comment: problem means file is not uploaded successfully, no file in server but get no errors message. yes, we have turned on errors and warnings.

Comment: Not sure what framework, CMS, library you are using. You need to give us more context.

Comment: We use Code Igniter

Answer (score 0):

#### Add the following to your webroot .htaccess

#### Step 1. enable mod_php (if not already enabled) for PHP5.x do:

`apt-get install php5-common libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli`

Then add the following to your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_value upload_max_filesize 900M
        php_value post_max_size 900M
        php_value memory_limit 256M
        php_value max_execution_time 1200
        php_value max_input_time 1200
</IfModule>
```

If not working try to add the following in your VirtualHost configuration

```
<Directory "/var/www/domain.com/public_html">
    php_admin_value post_max_size 150M
    php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 150M
    php_admin_value memory_limit 150M
    ...
</Directory>
```

Adjust to fit your need and restart the web server.

`service apache2 restart`

I hope it helps

Comment: @adiany sorry to hear that.  I updated the answer with alternative, hope it works.  NOTE: I added how to enable mod_php to first answer.